# Помогите разобраться с Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

Здрасьте!
Хотел вывести на экран содержимое БД.
Написал вот так:

```
$link = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$base);
$show_catalog = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `library`.`catalog` ");
   $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_catalog);
      foreach($res as $tgh) { 
         echo $tgh;     
  }
```

И получил сообщение **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Как я понимаю, оно обозначает, что данные, пришедшие из переменной **show_catalog** не являются массивом.

Видимо, я не понимаю работу функции **mysqli_fetch_assoc**, ибо думал, она создаст массив из этих данных.

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку

Comment: `mysqli_query` вернул false

Comment: Попимо возможной ошибки в `mysqli_query`, `mysqli_fetch_assoc` может возвращать `null` если в результате нет данных.

Comment: если mysqli_query вернул false - то варнинг бы был от mysqli_fetch_assoc. А так варнинг от foreach - значит запрос вернул 0 строк.